# Adding AspectJ to existing project

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, spring-aop

I am using spring-security project to try out OAuth2 server implementation. I have cloned the git project from https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security-oauth.

The example is working as documented. Now to trace the flow, I want to add function entry/exit using AOP to existing code. For this I have done following changes:

- Added a class "Watcher.java" (code below)
- Added AspectJ dependencies in pom.xml

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.3</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.3</version>
  </dependency>
  ```
- Project builds and runs
- But do not see the AspectJ markers for each function

Is it possible to add function entry/exit logging with this method without changing much of the original code?

Watcher.java:

```
package org.springframework.security.oauth.examples.sparklr;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterReturning;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

@Aspect
public class Watcher {

    @Pointcut("execution(* *(..))")
    public void watch() {
    }

    @Before("watch()")
    public void preWatch(JoinPoint joinPoint) {

        if (joinPoint.getArgs().length > 0) {
            String[] args = new String[joinPoint.getArgs().length];

            System.arraycopy(joinPoint.getArgs(), 0, args, 0,
            joinPoint.getArgs().length);

            System.out.println("-> " + joinPoint.toShortString()
                    + Arrays.toString(joinPoint.getArgs()));
        } else {
            System.out.println("-> " + joinPoint.toShortString());
        }

        System.out.println("Args: " + joinPoint.getArgs().length);
    }

    @AfterReturning("watch()")
    public void postWatch(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        System.out.println("<- " + joinPoint.toShortString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should enable AspectJ in spring configuration (to scan automagically your annotations)

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="..."/>
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
    ...
</beans>
```

Maybe you will nedd to the `spring-aop` dependency to your project too.